# Can I inherit an object's specific member variables?

Tags: python, oop

I have a parent object that has specific member variables that I want to inherit. I want this parent object to track children objects that are instantiated inside the parent object.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, someInfo, someOtherInfo):
         self.surname = someInfo
         self.otherInfo = someOtherInfo

    ##This function only executes if some condition is met in another function
    def spawnChild(self, childInfo):
        childName = "Kyle"
        self.children.append(child(childName))

class Child:
    def __init__(self, firstName):
        self.firstName = firstName
```

I want my child class to inherit the class member functions, which I know I could do with:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, firstName, someInfo, someOtherInfo):
        super().__init__(someInfo, someOtherInfo)
```

But I want to be more specific and inherit the object's states aswell. My end result would be the parent object giving a firstName to the child class, but the child object inherting the Parent's surname. However, I do not want to reinstantiate a new Object every single time I create a new Child object.

I want to use the existing parent object to create child Objects, that inherit it's parent's specific states and functions.

Another question, When inheriting classes, does this create a new class combined with the derived and base class, or will it just be a derived class with a reference to the inherited class? Asking for optimisation purposes, because I plan on instantiating a lot of derived objects.

Comment: You inherit from a whole class, not specific objects.

Comment: Inheritance is not used to implement relationships between different objects. A subclass is a kind of its superclass, e.g. Dog is a subclass of Mammal. You shouldn't use it to represent parent-child relationships.

Comment: @Barmar So I how can I represent parent-child relationships?

Comment: Use references between different objects. `self.father = x`